# Problem with LAN connection in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I asked this question two times before but I got no response. 
I am having a problem connecting LAN cable with Ubuntu. When I start my computer it will connect with the cable and a light will glow at the LAN port in my laptop. But as soon as the cable gets disconnected it won't reconnect. I will have to put the laptop in sleep mode and then wake it up and then it will again connect. This issue is only happening in Ubuntu. My computer is dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and this problem is occurring only in Ubuntu. Please help me.

Comment: Hi Nikhil Rathore - sorry to hear you've had no suggestions the last two times you've asked your question. Hopefully someone who knows how to troubleshoot this sort of ethernet problem will offer some good advice. We can assume it's probably an Ubuntu specific problem (because the same issue doesn't occur with Windows), so it might be worth trying a newer kernel while you're waiting for someone more knowledgable than me to offer a better suggestion. Try a recent 4.17 or 4.18 kernel using UKUU: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the thing is some days back it was working just fine and since I have installed ubuntu I haven't upgraded the kernel

Comment: It's possible, although not certain, that a small incremental update to the kernel has changed the behaviour. It's worth checking because it's quite easy to test - from the Grub menu you can select Advanced options for Ubuntu. The 1st option (with a recovery mode option underneath it) is your current kernel and any other entries are the 'older' ones. You might find a couple of different 4.15 kernels (4.15.0-30, 4.15.0-32 etc) & can check whether the ethernet behaviour works with one of them - it just helps narrow down whether a kernel update has changed it from 'working fine' to 'misbehaving'.